Docker host not taken from testcontainers config
I have a java spring project with tests in testcontainers.
My development env is a laptop with linux.
For setup local development env used podman-compose file: works goods (no problem).
But I have a problem with local podman with testcontainers (doesn't work).
To resolve it, I can run testcontainers on remote docker.
But intellij idea (or even in terminal) doesn't see docker.host variable from .testcontainers file(from user directory and from project test directore also).
I can change system env from local DOCKER_HOST to remote host only by calling "export DOCKER_HOST=" before calling gradle or maven build.
Why "docker.host=" variable in .testcontainers file doesn't sense for my test on build?

Please check the docs for podman: https://java.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/#podman

do you mean the file ~/.testcontainers.properties? or where do you have the .testcontainers file?

yeah.
property in ~/.testcontainers.properties

I'm expected this one
https://java.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#customizing-docker-host-detection
